# Visual Web Developer to access DB with password

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, vwdexpress

I am using Visual Web Developer Express 2010. It is running on Server 2003 with ASP.NET 4.

As I add my GridView and choose my DataSource (which is a password protected MDB file) it connects just fine. It does ask me for the password twice throughout the process. I enter it and I perform the test query option and all seems fine.

However, once I test the page in the browser I receive a rude error page stating: `[OleDbException (0x80040e4d): Not a valid password.]`

I am guessing that the password I entered during the setup of the DataSource is not being saved. How do I enter in the password so the form keeps it? Web.config or code? I have gone crossed eyed searching for this with VWD Express.

Comment: well a copy of your connection string entry would help track the problem down